# Automating Excel Pivot Tables with Python (SQL query data source)

Tags: python, sql, excel, win32com, xlsxwriter

The company I work for has multiple clients that still require excel pivot tables for data reporting. I have been pushing for a cloud dashboard solution, although it is unlikely this will change and I would like to automate the process. My goal is to have the excel files built with pivot tables and sent to clients on monthly deliverable dates. I have had various issues working with python libraries such as openpyxl(memory errors) and xlsxwriter(only can create new files).

It did not take long for me to get a SQL pyodbc connection going for queries, however due to memory and complexity issues I have been writing to the excel file with xlsxwriter. It would have been ideal to open pre built xlsm pivot table excel files and over write the data source sheet, however with openpyxl the program would crash due to memory error when writing all the rows and saving. One table I query as an example has 90 columns and over 100,000 rows. Xlsxwriter does not support opening pre existing excel files, so my current solution is to somehow save the xlsx file as xlsm then run a VBA macro to build the pivot table. (VBA cannot be exceuted in a non-macro enabled workbook). Below I have posted the last functions of code that dumps the SQL Query into the excel file then saves as XLSM.

```py
def makeWB(cursor,database,query,date,progress):
    ## cant open existing file with xlwriter

    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('PivotTable.'+database+'.'+date+'.xlsx')
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet("Data Dictionary")
    cnt = 1

    #Add field description page
    for line in open(path+database+".csv"):
        csv_row = line.split(",")
        worksheet.write_row('A'+str(cnt), csv_row)
        cnt = cnt+1

    #source data sheet
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet("Data")
    worksheet.write_row('A1', [i[0] for i in cursor.description])

    bar = Bar('  Writing to '+database, max=progress)
    rowcnt = 1
    cnt = 0
    for row in cursor:
        for x in range(len(row)):
            worksheet.write(rowcnt, x, row[x])
        rowcnt += 1
        bar.next()
    bar.finish()
    workbook.close()
```

This attmept at saving as xlsm worked with win32com.client

```py
def convert(filename,path):
    excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
    wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(path+"\\"+filename)
    excel.Visible = True
    xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled = 52
    wb.SaveAs(path+"\\Ald.xlsm", FileFormat = xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled)
    wb.Close(True)
```

Everything is correctly inputted to the excel files, I was hoping to get some further insight on how I can actually get the pivot tables built. Would my best option from this point be inject some vba script into the xlsm file then running it, or am I approaching this problem wrong? In the end I am trying to help my coworkers better understand practices for making processes automated and reusable while also speeding up simple tasks. I'm basically asking for advise and criticism so if anyone has any, I'm all ears.

Comment: Could you build a data connection to the csv file, instead of loading it through VBA? Refreshing the connection to the csv file will be faster than writing line by line.

Comment: @chucklukowski this may be a solution, however can pivot tables be built from comma delimted files?  The main issue is that I need to deliver the pivot tables, can you elaborate on your thought process further? im assuming you mean using the csv file as a middle stage from the sql server?    (I should also make note, the SQL tables I query change every month. Who ever made the Stored Procedures structured each month of data to have its own "data.Pivot_table" table )

Comment: Yes, create a blank sheet in Excel named 'DATA'. Create data connection to the csv file (I use Power Query add-in) and store the linked data on the DATA sheet. Create pivot tables from that. Refresh data connection to update what is pulled into Excel from csv files. Refresh pivot tables to update the pivot tables. So, in the end your python script would query database, export csv, open excel, refresh connections, save file version for client.

Comment: I tried creating a data connection with a csv file and it was extremely fast! I guess my next test is to see if I can use Win32com client python module do change data connection strings in the csv settings. Thank you for your suggestion

Comment: I'd be interested to see the code if you got that working. An alternative idea would be to record a macro of setting up the connection with VBA.